# Clipanion can't serve commands

Tags: node.js, typescript

I made some test CLI according to official Clipanion docs (https://mael.dev/clipanion/docs/getting-started#execute-your-cli) and even cloned that example - https://github.com/i5ting/clipanion-test,  but I have no idea why i can't execute my commands.

Most likely I have the problem with understanding how this tool works in general. So there are my steps:

1. Clone the project
2. Make sure that i have installed all necessary dependencies
3. Build the project (`yarn prepack`)
4. Execute the command from the root of the project

Here is what I'm getting:

```
zsh: command not found: clipanion
```

I'm running into this on macOS

Have I missed something in my steps?

Answer (score 0):

Found the root of it

The thing is that clipanion doesn't provide functionality I expected. It makes your script powerful but you should make it executable and provide a runtime for it on your own.